# Display two ul (display: inline) in the same row

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a site (just to learn, is not an actual website) and at the top there's links to different sections of the page. The HTML goes as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/shift.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="nav">
      <div class="container">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Airbnb logo</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Browse</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="header">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Find a place to stay.</h1>
        <p>Rent from people in over 34,000 cities and 192 countries.</p>
      </div>
    </div> 

    <div class="learn-more">
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <h3>Travel</h3>
            <p>From apartments and rooms to treehouses and boats: stay in unique spaces in 192 countries.</p>
            <p><a href="#">See how to travel on Airbnb</a></p>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>Host</h3>
            <p>Renting out your unused space could pay your bills or fund your next vacation.</p>
            <p><a href="#">Learn more about hosting</a></p>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>Trust and Safety</h3>
            <p>From Verified ID to our worldwide customer support team, we've got your back.</p>
            <p><a href="#">Learn about trust at Airbnb</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now I am trying to style the page, but I want all the elements of the navbar in the same line.

So far I have:

```
.nav a {
  color: #5a5a5a;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 14px 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav li {
    display: inline;
}

.header {
  background-image:url('http://bit.ly/1KIFZoI');
  background-size: cover;
  height: 300px;
}

.header h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 48px;  
  font-family: 'Shift', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.header p {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

However, the display: inline; still leaves my navbar in two lines. I want them all in the same line if possible not putting all the elements in the same list (same ul)

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do this:

```
ul{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

> Beware: you have default padding in the `<ul>`, because of that you
>   have a gap between them. Just add `padding:0` and/or `margin:0`to the
>   `<ul>` to eliminate the gap ( adjust your needs ).

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/z8g1yobf/)**

Comment: Thanks! :) (I don't know who downvoted that, I surely didn't, let me know if I can do something to help you)